# Best way to show/popup SSL certificate information

Tags: ssl, browser, https

How to put a link (icon, ...) into my web page to show the current SSL certificate information?

The simplest way could be put a link to some online site validator (third party or our own) but if possible the built-in popup browser information would be great.

I think it is useful to emphasize the SSL security (e.g. near to "buy" button) or when exists frames and/or multiple resources involved, or it is unknown the specific certificate used, ...

Exists some way to do it?

Thanks!

UPDATED:

1. As an example of external verification provider [Symantec seal](http://www.symantec.com/en/uk/ssl/seal-agreement/install.jsp?inid=abox_seal_link)
2. I'm looking for pop up the built in browser certificate information (e.g. with two domains, one as parent document and other as framed content, the user can see, easilly, the most top, but not the inner most certificate).

Comment: Such a pop would at best be useless and at worst be misleading. As Steffen Ullrich says, it's up to the browser to display the security information, which only it can verify. Pretending that the webpage itself knows anything about the certificate with which it was served only encourages confusion for the user, since it doesn't prove anything at all.

Comment: @Bruno, many sites provide that information in some ways, eg. ebay show *two* icons with certified SSL verification (from TRUSTe and Norton) and could be "falsified" by the website. I don't asking if you agree with me, just if it can be made. Steffen response is not a solution, only their opinion (but you can upvote of course).

Comment: I know, I'm just saying this is pure smoke and mirrors as sold by the CAs. No benefits at all. It can also be quite damaging since it's obviously easy to forge.

Comment: _"No benefits at all"_ it's **your** opinion, I respect but it's not my question.

Comment: I understand it's not your question, but you don't seem to understand the benefits (or lack thereof). (a) Anyone can put any picture with any link on their website, including forgers. (b) Even if the link from the seal to the CA verification shows that that CA has indeed issued a cert for that name, and that it gets it now, doesn't prove in any way that the user's browser has seen that very same cert (there could be a MITM between the browser and the website, but not between the CA and the website). Hence, that doesn't actually tell the user anything useful.

Comment: The browser already (a) 'emphasise[s] the SSL security' by showing a padlock icon, and (b) provides a way to view the certificate associated with the page. @Bruno and Steffen are 100% correct about this. Save your time.

Comment: On the other hand... _"provides a way to view the certificate associated with the page"_ **Sure?** have you tried **MY** example? (e.g. on firefox)

Comment: The fact that these seals don't prove anything is a fact, not an opinion, and we've explained to you why. Your users wanting such a seal may also be a fact, I don't dispute that. It's just unfortunate that what users looking for this believe is just an illusion that CAs encourage to propagate (if you think about it, such a seal is free advertising for them). Like I said, when you click on such a seal (like your example), you're verifying the certificate that the CA's gets, not the certificate that your user gets.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do this and I don't think it is a good idea: The access to the information about the certificate must be in control of the user, not the site. Otherwise the site could claim anything it wants. Also links to an online validator are misleading, because the site might look different from validator then from the user.

Apart from that, just the use of SSL says not much about the security of the site. Anybody can get such a certificate and still store passwords unencrypted, loose credit card information, get hacked or spread malware.

Comment: My question is not about user experience is about how to show some information. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Anything on the page itself is controlled by the website or an attacker in between. This means that any seals or popups are only security theater which also attackers use already to lure the user. I hope that in the long run the perceived value of this seals will vanish and they might even be seen as (maybe false) self-advertising of the sites and reduce the trust.

Comment: No, I'm a security professional hating security theater :) "not a single objective response to my objective question" - it might be because other people hate security theater too, and thats what I mean with "the perceived value of this seals will vanish".

Comment: By the way, it could be useful... _"**Answer the question** Read the question carefully. What, **specifically**, is the question asking for?"_ [Inline Link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: The question is asking for a feature (way to show information about the certificate of the current connection inside the web page) and the answer says that the feature is not available and explains why it should not be available.  No need to accept the answer if you don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

> How to put a link (icon, ...) into my web page to show the current SSL certificate information?

As far as I know there isn't such a feature, and implementing such a feature in browsers wouldn't be a good idea.

Checking the security of the connection between your user and your website is something that you can unfortunately not do anything about. Whatever you may do from your end will at best be a gimmick, and at worst be something that gives the user a false sense of security, possibly mislead them into checking the wrong things and encouraging attackers to mimic those signs you're trying to display.

This is actually quite a fundamental security principle, which can only be solved by educating the user (and this is where trying to make them check the wrong thing can lead to more harm than good).

To quote [Iszi from Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8824/if-i-send-a-fax-from-an-unsecure-endpoint-to-a-secure-endpoint-is-the-data-secu#comment14144_8824): "*if you have to ask "is this line secure?", then the answer is "no".*"

Anything that you do from the website's end is potentially something that a forger could do.

Imaging a situation where you can indeed click and have some popup showing the websites security website there and then. This would take a very observant user to have to look for the signs of a genuine browser dialog and a fake pop-up.

It is ultimately the user's responsibility to check that HTTPS is used and that it is used correctly.

That's a more general security issue, not specific to computing in fact. If a customer walks into a fake bank impersonating the name of a legitimate bank to deposit money, the legitimate bank cannot do anything about it. Only the user is in a position to make any required verification at the time they enter the building.

From a security perspective, the information you're trying to show is something for which the presentation should NOT be controlled by the website you are visiting. These verifications *have* to be done by the browser itself for them to be of any use, otherwise they would be trivial to forge.

User interfaces that confuse what comes from the browser and what comes from the website are generally bad for security. (This is why [full screen mechanisms](http://feross.org/html5-fullscreen-api-attack/) must have browser-specific UI components, that cannot be forged by the site, otherwise, they would introduce a security risk.)

The next best thing you can do is to try to educate your users in general: for example show is a quick tutorial explaining to your user how to check the certificate in their browser. This won't help at all there and then if there is an actual attack, but it can help in the long term. This is the strategy used by banks when they keep telling you "*Don't ever give your PIN code or password to anyone, none of our employees will ever request them*": this simply encourages users to be alerted when someone who claims to be an employee one day tries to get those details. The bank won't be able to do anything between the user and the fake bank employee (since it won't even be there), but at least it will have tried to educate the user in advance.

---

From a user's point of view, being able to assess how secure the connection is can be a tricky exercise, not always helped by changes in the user-interface. The other similar system you mention is the external security seal, as provided by many CAs. Unfortunately, they're not a great idea either...

> On the other hand... "provides a way to view the certificate associated with the page" Sure? have you tried MY example? (e.g. on firefox)

Let's try with your example indeed. Without needing to try the form on the [page you link to](http://www.symantec.com/en/uk/ssl/seal-agreement/install.jsp), we can see such a seal because it is at the bottom of that very page. There is a logo that says "... Secured, powered by ...", with a [link to a certificate verification service](https://trustsealinfo.verisign.com/splash?form_file=fdf/splash.fdf&dn=www.symantec.com&lang=en), which shows information that looks reassuring on the face of it, such as "*This website can secure your private information using a SSL Certificate. Information exchanged with any address beginning with https is encrypted using SSL before transmission.*".

It all *looks* good.

Now, firstly, I got that seal on a page serve in plain HTTP, so that certainly doesn't prove anything on that page itself. Let's just pretend that it was obvious to all users that only pages served with `https://` on that same host name would be protected with that seal.

When the user's browser (U) makes a connection to the site (S), it gets a certificate (CS_from_U): this is the one that the users wants to verify.

When the user's browser connects to the trust seal info site (T), this system shows the certificate that it has been able to get (CS_from_T), but the browser hasn't sent any information about the certificate it has seen (CS_from_U) to T.

The connection from U to S (which uses CS_from_U), the connection from U to T and the connection from T to S (which uses CS_from_T) are three distinct connections.

What T tells U about the certificate is in fact about CS_from_T, the legitimate certificate. There could be a MITM attack between U and S that makes CS_from_U be a different certificate from CS_from_T (in fact, some webfarms use different certificates sometimes too, without there being an attack anyway).

Of course, that illegitimate CS_from_U certificate would still have to be issued by something trusted by the user's browser, but this could happen with a manual exception, a corporate MITM proxy, or another CA that made a mistake.

Effectively, this seal verification doesn't prove much about the certificate seen by the user. It mainly proves that the legitimate server has indeed purchased a certificate from that CA. It certainly does not prove that another certificate was not issued by another CA or that the certificate seen by the user at the time is the certificate that was legitimately issued by the CA.

Of course, the probability of the risks are very hard to assess. The hard part for an attacker is to be in a position to perform that MITM attack and to have possession of a certificate that is going to be trusted by the user (e.g. coming from a rogue CA), which is hopefully unlikely. At that stage, what the seal verifier shows is completely irrelevant.

In the end, the seal logo mainly provides the illusion of security to the user, since what it checks assumes that what it shows has not been tampered with. Any logical reasoning that postulates there is no problem can reach the conclusion that there is no problem indeed.

On the up side, [this particular seal](https://trustsealinfo.verisign.com/splash?form_file=fdf/splash.fdf&dn=www.symantec.com&lang=en) is about more than the certificate: it has a malware scan and vulnerability assessment section, which can certainly be a good thing in general. I'm not sure whether other CAs to this, but this sort of service can be useful.

I'm not trying to discredit the CA system in general, and I have nothing against that particular CA used in this example. The CA system is full of imperfections, but it is hard to come up with better solutions that are so generally applicable. What I'm trying to point out is that such a seal system offers no real security regarding the certificate. However, what such a seal does is advertise the CA to each of its customer's visitors, hence they have a vested interest in telling people to use these.

---

To conclude:

- If your motivation to do this is to help the user from a security point of view, the best thing you can do is to try to educate them. To prevent UI elements to be forged, these verifications *have* to be initiated by the user and done via the browser, not the website.
- If instead of, or in addition to this, you also have to go through a box-ticking exercise and show some symbol that looks pretty (possibly due to commercial pressure), simply stick the seal you're already getting from your CA on your webpage.

Comment: A more direct answer to what you want is in the last 3 paragraphs. "*User interfaces that confuse what comes from the browser and what comes from the website are generally bad for security. [...]*". More directly to the point: AFAIK this is not possible, and if it was, it would need to be done *very* carefully by the browser implementors so that a fake popup could not be confused with the real one. Implementing this would *increase* that risk unfortunately.

Comment: Sincerely you are far far away, your solution is a tutorial? XD XD (also hackable? :P ). No mention to the frame/resources problem? (how to show associated certificates **easily** to the user). **ONE USER** is watching one certification provider (e.g. GeoTrust) on the url bar **but** the inframe (and/or resources) come from **OTHER** (e.g. Symantec). I would like to watch your tutorial...

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying: there is no good solution to your problem, because only the user can verify the certificate the browser see and initiate this action.

Comment: That's a more general security issue, not specific to computing in fact. If a customer walks into a fake bank impersonating the name of a legitimate bank to deposit money, the legitimate bank cannot do anything about it. Only the user is in a position to make any required verification at the time they enter the building.

Comment: Yes, your are looking for a secure solution for the user. What I'm saying is that you cannot perform this step for the user. **Only** the user is able to verify what they are using at the time they are using it. This **has** to be done via the browser itself, not by whatever your site may be sending to the browser. Anything else **will** make that verification vulnerable to flaws.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you then looking for something that will display the certificate information, preferably as seen by the browser and not by a third-party seal system, **irrespectively** of the security aspects associated with such a mechanism?

Comment: Show me one way and I will estimate performance, development costs, deploy costs, risks, **security**, user experience, ... **BUT NOW** you can reread my **simple** question.

Comment: What we've been trying to explain to you is that there isn't a way, and if there was one, it wouldn't add any security benefit but add confusion instead, hence that would be a good reason to get such a feature removed.

Comment: I realise you were getting a bit annoyed about this yesterday. I've tried to rearrange everything to make it a more direct answer. Your question is indeed straightforward, its solutions are not, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for your effort @Bruno.